# When the Moon is higher in Naples Sky

Tags: python, pyephem

I wanted to calculate the time for which the Moon is higher for a local observer, so I have put together the following code, using a rather brute force approach

```
import ephem as x
from ephem.cities import city
# the time unit is a day, here we define day, hour, etc
d, h, m, s = 1.0, 1.0/24, 1.0/24/60, 1.0/24/60/60

my_city = 'Naples'
me  = city(my_city)
me2 = city(my_city)
moon = x.Moon()

def velocity(date):
    me2.date=date-0.1*s
    moon.compute(me2) ; alt0 = moon.alt
    me2.date=date+0.1*s
    moon.compute(me2) ; alt1 = moon.alt
    return alt1/0.2/s - alt0/0.2/s

me.date = "2022/01/01 00:00:01"
moon.compute(me)

mtt = moon.transit_time
time = x.Date(x.newton(velocity,mtt-0.2*h,mtt+0.2*h))
```

My code works, like if I plot the times and the elevations I have a "sinusoidal", and if I place the full Moon on the curve I see that it's higher near the Winter solstice...

I'd like to know if there is a less brute force approach to the solution of my problem, using possibly PyEphem, that I superficially know, or another Python package.

Comment: This question (or lack thereof) isn't well suited for stackoverflow. I would recommend https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @Luke Before posting I thought about the relevance of the question on SO, and concluded that it's  OK.  It's true that my approach sort of works, but I cannot be sure of the accuracy of the final result, so I'm looking for a more analytical one.  In other words, the problem is not in bad coding (aka posting in codereview) but in a better algorithm, that imo seems to fit in SO format.

Comment: As you state " the problem is not in bad coding (aka posting in codereview) but in a better algorithm,"  Then it should include the algorithm tag and not the python tag